Muckenhoupt $A_P$ weights are invariant under dilation proof verification
This exercise is from Loukas Grafokas Classical Fourier Analysis.
Exercise:
Let $w \in A_p$ for some $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $\lambda >0$. Then
\begin{equation*}
 [w^\lambda]_{A_p} = [w]_{A_p} \quad , \text{where} ~~ w^\lambda = w(\lambda x)
\end{equation*}
Proof:
For the case $1 <p <\infty$ : Let $x \in \{u : u \in Q\}$ , then we have $x \in \{\frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \lambda u : u \in Q\}$. Set $\lambda u = \hat{u}$, we have that $x \in \{\frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \hat{u} : \frac{\hat{u}}{\lambda} \in Q\}$ and this gives
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{|Q|}\displaystyle\int_{Q} w(\lambda x)dx 
 &=\frac{1}{|Q|}\displaystyle\int_{\{u: u \in Q\}} w(\lambda x)dx =\frac{1}{|Q|}\displaystyle\int_{\{\frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \hat{u} : \frac{\hat{u}}{\lambda} \in Q\}} w(\lambda x)dx  
\end{align*}
Since
\begin{align*}
\left\{\frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \hat{u} : \frac{\hat{u}}{\lambda} \in Q \right\} 
&=  \left\{\frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \hat{u} : \left|\left| \frac{\hat{u}}{\lambda} - C_Q\right| \right|_{\infty} < r_Q \right\} =  \left\{\frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \hat{u} : \left|\left| \hat{u} - \lambda C_Q\right| \right|_{\infty} < \lambda r_Q \right\}  
\end{align*}
Let $\bar{u}=\lambda x$, so $\bar{u} \in  \left\{\hat{u} : \hat{u} \in \lambda Q \right\}$ and we have that
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{|Q|}\displaystyle\int_{Q} w(\lambda x)dx 
 &=\frac{1}{|Q|}\displaystyle\int_{\{\frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \hat{u} : \frac{\hat{u}}{\lambda} \in Q\}} w(\lambda x)dx =\frac{1}{|Q|}\displaystyle\int_{\left\{\hat{u} : \hat{u} \in \lambda Q \right\}} w(\bar{u}) \frac{1}{\lambda^n}d\bar{u} \\
 &= \frac{1}{|\lambda Q|}\displaystyle\int_{\left\{\hat{u} : \hat{u} \in \lambda Q \right\}} w(\bar{u}) d\bar{u}
\end{align*}
Similarly
\begin{align*}
 \left(\frac{1}{|Q|} \displaystyle\int_{Q} (w(\lambda x))^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}dx\right)^{p-1} 
 &= \left(\frac{1}{|Q|} \displaystyle\int_{\{u: u \in Q\}} (w(\lambda x))^{-\frac{1}{p-1}} dx\right)^{p-1} \\
 &= \left(\frac{1}{|Q|} \displaystyle\int_{\{\frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \hat{u} : \frac{\hat{u}}{\lambda} \in Q\}} (w(\lambda x))^{-\frac{1}{p-1}} dx\right)^{p-1} \\
 &=\left(\frac{1}{|Q|} \displaystyle\int_{\{ \hat{u} : \hat{u} \in Q\}} (w(\bar{u} ))^{-\frac{1}{p-1}} \frac{1}{\lambda^n} d\bar{u}\right)^{p-1} \\
 &= \left(\frac{1}{|\lambda Q|} \displaystyle\int_{\{ \hat{u} : \hat{u} \in Q\}} (w(\bar{u}))^{-\frac{1}{p-1}} d\bar{u}\right)^{p-1} 
\end{align*}
Denote $R= \lambda Q$, then we have
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1}{|Q|}\displaystyle\int_{Q} w^\lambda dx\right) \left(\frac{1}{|Q|} \displaystyle\int_{Q} (w^\lambda)^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}dx\right)^{p-1} =\left(\frac{1}{|R|}\displaystyle\int_{R} wdx\right) \left(\frac{1}{|R|} \displaystyle\int_{R} w^{-\frac{1}{p-1}} dx\right)^{p-1} 
\end{align*}
Taking the supremum of $Q$, we have
\begin{align*}
[w^\lambda]_{A_p} =\left(\frac{1}{|R|} \displaystyle\int_{R} wdx\right) \left(\frac{1}{|R|} \displaystyle\int_{R} w^{-\frac{1}{p-1}} dx \right)^{p-1} 
\end{align*}
Taking the supremum of $R$, we have $[w^\lambda]_{A_p} = [w]_{A_p}$.
\For the case $p=1$:
By the above , we have that
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{|Q|}\displaystyle\int_{Q} w(x)dx  = \frac{1}{|R|}\displaystyle\int_{R} w(x)dx 
\end{align*}
Let $a>0$ be such that $w^{-1} (\lambda x) \leq a$, for all $x \in Q \backslash N$, for some $N$ with $|N|=0$.
\Fix an $x \in Q \backslash N$, then by letting $u = \lambda x$, we have
\begin{align*}
 w^{-1}(u) \leq a \quad \text{and} \quad u \in \lambda Q \backslash \lambda N, \quad \text{where} \quad \lambda Q =\{\lambda u : u \in Q\} 
\end{align*}
But $|\lambda N| = \lambda^n |N| =0$, so $w^{-1} (u) \leq a$, for all $u \in \lambda Q \backslash \lambda N$.
\Hence $w^{-1}(u) \leq a$ and so $$||w^{-1}(\lambda x)||_{L^{\infty}(Q)} \geq ||w^{-1}(\lambda x)||_{L^{\infty}(\lambda Q)} := ||w^{-1}(\lambda x)||_{L^{\infty}(R)}.$$
Similarly, let $b >0$ be such that $w^{-1}(x) \leq b$ for all $x \in \lambda Q \backslash \lambda M$, for some $M$ with $|M|=0$.
\Fix an $x \in \lambda Q \backslash \lambda M$, then by letting $\lambda u = x$, we have
\begin{align*}
 w^{-1}(\lambda u) \leq a \quad \text{and} \quad u \in \frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot\lambda Q \backslash \frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \lambda N = Q \backslash M
\end{align*}
But $|\lambda M| = \lambda^n |M| =0$, so $w^{-1} (\lambda u) \leq a$, for all $u \in Q \backslash M$.
\Hence $w^{-1}(\lambda u) \leq a$ and so $$||w^{-1}(\lambda x)||_{L^{\infty}(Q)} \leq ||w^{-1}(x)||_{L^{\infty}(Q)}.$$ Therefore  $$||w^{-1}(\lambda x)||_{L^{\infty}(Q)} = ||w^{-1}(x)||_{L^{\infty}(Q)}.$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
 [w^\lambda]_{A_1} 
 &= [w(\lambda x)]_{A_1} = \displaystyle\sup_{\text{Q~ cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$}} \left(\frac{1}{|Q|} \displaystyle\int_{Q} wdx\right) ||w^{-1}||_{L^{\infty}(Q)} \\
 &=\displaystyle\sup_{\text{R~ cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$}} \left(\frac{1}{|R|} \displaystyle\int_{R} wdx\right) ||w^{-1}||_{L^{\infty}(R)} = [w]_{A_1}
\end{align*}
Hence $[w^{\lambda}]_{A_1} = [w]_{A_1}$ , for $1 \leq p < \infty$.
\We conclude that $[w^\lambda]_{A_p} = [w]_{A_p} \quad , \text{where~~} w^\lambda = w(\lambda x)$, for some $1 \leq p < \infty$.
Is my proof correct?
Definition 1:
Let $1 < p < \infty$ and $w$ be a weight. The expression
\begin{equation} 
 [w]_{A_p} = \displaystyle\sup_{\text{Q cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$}} \left(\frac{1}{|Q|} \displaystyle\int_Q w dx \right) \left(\frac{1}{|Q|} \displaystyle\int_Q w^{-\frac{1}{p-1}} dx\right)^{p-1}
\end{equation}
is the $A_p$ Muckenhoupt characteristic constant of $w$, or simply the $A_p$ characteristic constant of $w$.
Definition 2:
A function $w(x) \geq 0$ is called an $A_1$ weight if
\begin{equation} \label{eq30}
 M_{w}^{'} (x) \leq C w(x) \quad , \quad \text{for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$}
\end{equation}
for some constant $C$.If $w$ is an $A_1$ weight, then the $($finite$)$ quantity
\begin{equation} 
 [w]_{A_1} = \displaystyle\sup_{\text{Q cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$}} \left(\frac{1}{|Q|} \displaystyle\int_Q w dx \right) ||w^{-1}||_{L^\infty (Q)}
\end{equation}
is called the $A_1$ Muckenhoupt characteristic constant of $w$, or simply the $A_1$ characteristic constant of $w$.
